# Move elements from one element to another according to the width of the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 containers. One contains 3 element and the other has only one. Basically I want to achieve two things:

1. When the user decreases the window width (by resizing it) and it reaches a certain value, I want to move some elements from one container to another.
2. When the user increases the window width (by resizing it) and it reaches a certain value, I want to move theses items back to the previous container.

Here's what I've done so far:

```js
var referenceWidth; // global variable to hold the viewport width reference. It's used to compare with the actual width.

window.onload = function() {
  referenceWidth = window.innerWidth; // assings the current window width to be used as a reference later.
}

window.onresize = function() { // monitors the resizing of the window
  var actualWidth = window.innerWidth; // assigns the current window width.
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent'); // take all parent elements (in the project there will be more than one).

  if (actualWidth < referenceWidth) { // if the actualWidth is lower than the referenceWidth than...

    // check if it reaches a value between 1000px and 900px while decreasing window width.
    if (actualWidth <= 1000 && actualWidth >= 900) {
      // sends each parent and the actual size to the X function.
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        x(parent[i], actualWidth);
      }
    } else if (actualWidth <= 780 && actualWidth >= 680) { // check if it reaches a value between 780px and 680px while decreasing window width.
      // sends each parent and the actual size to the Y function.
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        x(parent[i], actualWidth);
      }
    }
    referenceWidth = actualWidth; // updates the referenceWidth value
  } else if (actualWidth > referenceWidth) {
    // check if it reaches a value between 1000px and 900px while increasing window width.
    if (actualWidth <= 1000 && actualWidth >= 900) {
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        y(parent[i], actualWidth);
      }
    } else if (actualWidth <= 790 && actualWidth >= 780) { // check if it reaches a value between 780px and 680px while increasing window width.
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        y(parent[i], actualWidth);
      }
    }
    referenceWidth = actualWidth; // update the referenceWidth
  }

  // the function that puts the element in another element.
  function x(o, u) {
    var child = o.children; // receives the children elements from the parent sent.
    var checkWidth = u >= 900; // check if the width is greater than 900px. If true, it means that the third item is supposed to be moved.

    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {

      switch (checkWidth) {
        // move the third item to next child
        case true:
          var item = child[i].children[2];
          item.classList.add("flag");
          child[i + 1].insertBefore(item, child[i + 1].firstChild);
          break;
          // move the second item to the next child
        case false:
          var item = child[i].children[1];
          item.classList.add("flag");
          child[i + 1].insertBefore(item, child[i + 1].firstChild);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  function y(o, u) {
    var child = o.children;
    var checkWidth = u >= 900;

    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
      // the following code is supposed to get the elements back to the first child, but it doesn't works properly.
      if (child[i].children.length < 3) {
        switch (checkWidth) {
          // move the first item from the next child to the current child.
          case true:
            var item = child[i + 1].children[0];
            child[i].append(item);
            break;

            // move the first item from the next child to the current child.
          case false:
            var item = child[i + 1].children[0];
            child[i].append(item);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 900px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  width: 206px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      <p>item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p>item 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p>item 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      <p>item 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the above code the following errors occur:

1. Sometimes the items do not go to the other element, mainly (but not only) when the user resizes the window very fast.
2. Some items change order when they return to the previous container (look at items 2 and 3).

How can I solve these problems? Or is there a better way to make the same thing?

Comment: I’d recommend using one of CSS’ new layout modes for this ([`grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) - this way you need no Javascript at all

Comment: Generally speaking, you can start by looking at the console: in some situations you have errors (`item is undefined` and `child[(i + 1)] is undefined`)